# Pyglet custom Event Loop fails with multiple windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I have a custom Event Loop for Pyglet that can be simplified to this simple piece of code

```
while True:
    pyglet.clock.tick()

    for window in pyglet.app.windows:
        window.switch_to()
        # rendering code
        window.flip()
        window.dispatch_events() # <--- program hangs
```

When there is only one window, the event loop works fine but when I attempt to have two windows, the loop hangs at window.dispatch_events(). Calling the functions in different order yield the same problem. I also tried debugging:

```
pyglet.options['debug_win32'] = True
```

Error Message:

```
...
_user32.UnregisterHotKey(self._hwnd, 0)
b'Hot key is not registered.\r\n'
```

After some more tinkering I managed to get the windows responsive with a dirty hack, but still there are quite a few issues that arise with event processing. Fix was calling an update immediately after setting window visible.

Sample Initialisation code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    engine = Engine()
    engine.run()

class Engine: # test program
    def __init__(self):
        self.application = customLib.Application()

        # define windows, by default they are set as not visible
        self.window1 = self.application.guiManager.createWindow("Window 1",
                                                          (1000, 700),
                                                          cursorPath="../data/cursor.png")

        self.window2 = self.application.guiManager.createWindow("Window 2",
                                                          (1000, 700),
                                                          cursorPath="../data/cursor.png")

        # load up code such as loading textures and .obj files

        self.window1.pygletWindow.set_visible()
        self.window1.update() # calling this after setting self.window2 visible will cause original error
        self.window2.pygletWindow.set_visible()
        self.window2.update()

    def run(self):
        self.application.run()

### CUSTOMLIB ###
class Application:
    ...
    def run(self):
        while True:
            pyglet.clock.tick()
            self.guiManager.update()

class GUIManager: # manages windows
    ...
    def update(self):
        for window in self.windows:
            window.update()

class Window: # pyglet window higher level wrapper
    pygletWindow = None
    ...
    def update(self):
        e = self.pygletWindow.dispatch_events()

        # all events are intercepted by a custom class, it transforms all unhandled events (keyboard, mouse, and close button for now) into a list of events that can then be looped through rather than requiring twenty different functions.
        # the event list is acquired, looped through and then cleared
        for event in self.eventManager.get():
            if event.type == customLib.CLOSE:
                # close application
            elif event.type == customLib.K_W:
                # move player forward

        # rendering
        self.pygletWindow.switch_to()
        # window is cleared
        # window content rendered
        self.pygletWindow.flip()
```

The way around the previous problem seems a little foolish and not robust. With the current event loop I have, window feedback sometimes does not work. For example, to close the window I must sometimes click it several times or, when moving the window around it won't always grab the window. I `dispatch_events()` at every loop and my custom event handler does not handle window motion events. The glitching of event handling only occurs with multiple windows. With a single window the event loop is flawless. This "bug" can be fixed by using varients of pyglet EventLoop.

I have concluded that a custom Event Loops' cons outweigh its pros. It is much easier to subclass EventLoop (since it's optimised for the OS) and override any pesky routines. Even better is to make a whole new event loop copying initialisation code of EventLoop and any backend routines (utilising PlatformEventLoop), which then allows you to very easily implement custom routines. I will be leaving this question up because there is very little documentation about this matter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many render iterations do you pass before the problem occurs? is it immediately or do you get a few render cycles before it happens? I'm asking because I suspect it might be because you never do `window.clear()` first, or it might be something silly as the fact that you never use the return from `window.dispatch_events()`, as if it's a generator, nothing will happen unless you "use" the return. Even tho this makes little sense, try doing `x = window.dispatch_events()` in the mean time, just to rid out any oddities.

Comment: Something that sticks out as well is `Too many posts were made to a semaphore.` which is a old classic way for Windows to tell developers they're hammering to often. Usually you can try/catch this and try again, and things will resume as per normal. Also your code isn't a straight copy paste, I see you've tried to write a good minimal example, which is nice. Just make sure you don't miss any logic (`self.pygletWindow.dispatch_events()` for instance, is the original code rather than `window.dispatch_events()`).

Comment: @Torxed I added the `x = window.dispatch_events()` just in case, even though there was no observable difference. Also tried to be more detailed in my code this time. When original error occurs, it never has an opportunity to render.